# Shading a map with underlying data in Julia

Tags: julia, geo

I want to create a map of Germany where each state is shaded according to its gross domestic product. I know how to do this in R (and put the code below). Is there a possibility to do this in Julia in an equally simple way?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

shpData = st_read("./geofile.shp")
GDPData <- read.delim("./stateGDP.csv", header=FALSE)
GDPData <- rename(GDPData,StateName=V1,GDP=V2)

GDPData %>%
  left_join(shpData) ->mergedData

ggplot(mergedData) + geom_sf(data = mergedData, aes(fill = BIP,geometry=geometry)) + coord_sf(crs = st_crs(mergedData))-> pBIP1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd load the Shapefile and use Plots to plot it.
The ideomatic code is something like

```
using Plots, Shapefile, CSV

shp = Shapefile.shapes(Shapefile.Table("geofile.shp"))
GDPData = CSV.read("stateGDP.csv")

plot(shp, fill_z = GDPData.V2')
```

Note the `'` which transposes the values to a column vector - this will tell Plots to apply the colors to individual polygons.

Comment: That looks very neat. Unfortunately,  the plotting command gives the error "ERROR: Cannot convert Shapefile.Polygon to series data for plotting". Not sure whether that is an issue with Plots.jl or something else. If I get it to work, I will report back.

Comment: I fixed it in a PR - added to the answer.

Comment: You can check out the fixed version if you like with `]add https://github.com/mkborregaard/GeoInterface.jl#master`

Comment: Should be a new release of GeoInterface now with the fix

Comment: I updated the answer as the new version has this functionality now.